# My position is higher than yours!

Tags: cipher

> General: I 41v9 p5w96 5v96 y52 b9c12s9 I 1m 1234567890.
>
> Soldier: Understood.

What did the general say?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I 41v9 p5w96 5v96 y52 b9c12s9 I 1m 1234567890

> I think this says “I have power over you because I am....”

Using the cipher substitution, we see that

> 1=A, 2=U, 4=H, 5=O, 6=R, 9=E.

Therefore the final word is

> AU_HOR__E_. It looks to be the word AUTHORIZED, so 3=T, 7=I, 8=Z, 0=D.

So the general said

> I have power over you because I am authorized.

---

How I broke this cipher:

> B9C12SE automatically looked like BECAUSE, which gave me 1,2,9. Then “I 4AVE” looked like “I HAVE”, which gave 4. Then “Y5U” looked like “YOU”, which gave 5. Then finally (before solving for the last word), “POWE6 OVE6” looked like “POWER OVER”, which gave 6.